# How to pass an argument in a function call?

Tags: javascript

```
function rp_marcadesmarcaFarm(valor) {

    FM_log(3, "marcadesmarcaFarm called = "+valor);

    for (i = 0; i < farmList.length; i++) {

        var arr        = farmList[i].split("|");
        var xy         = arr[0].split(",");
        var fvillageId = xy2id(parseInt(xy[0]), parseInt(xy[1]));

        GM_setValue("farmAtivada_"+suffixLocal+fvillageId, valor);
        GM_setValue("farmAtivada_"+suffixLocal+i, valor);
    };

    reloadFarmTable();
};

function createLinkButton(text, title, jsFunction, value) {   

  var button       = dom.cn("a");    
  button.href      = "javascript:void(0)";    
  button.innerHTML = text;    
  button.title     = title;

  if (jsFunction != null) {    
    button.addEventListener('click', jsFunction, false);    
  }

  return button;    
}

createLinkButton("X", T('CHECKFARM_M'), rp_marcadesmarcaFarm(true));
```

apparently the last argument (rp_marcadesmarcaFarm(true)) when invoking the createLinkButton is not working. If I change to:

```
createLinkButton("X", T('CHECKFARM_M'), rp_marcadesmarcaFarm);
```

it works. So how can I pass the (true) variable to the third argument of createLinkButton?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
createLinkButton("X", T('CHECKFARM_M'), function() {rp_marcadesmarcaFarm(true)});
```

Answer (score 1):

`createLinkButton` is waiting for a function, but `rp_marcadesmarcaFarm(true)` calls the function and actually pass the return value.

What you want is an anonymous function that will call `rp_marcadesmarcaFarm(true)` and pass that to `createLinkButton`

```
createLinkButton("X", T('CHECKFARM_M'), function(){ rp_marcadesmarcaFarm(true); });
```

Comment: cause when I click the button it invoke that function which does stuff.